# How do I add a loading spinner in React and Node app? (Nodemailer)

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I want to achieve something like when I click on the Send button, a spinner should appear near the button then transform the Send button into a Message Sent button. I could achieve that the button changes, but there is no loading time. Why does it happen immediately?

React Frontend:

```
import React from 'react';
import './contact.css';
import tick4 from './tick4.svg';
import copy from './copy.svg';
import axios from 'axios';

class Contact extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            loading: false,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { name, email, phone } = this.state;

        axios.post('/api/contact', {
            name,
            email,
            phone,
        });

        this.resetForm();
    }

    resetForm() {
        this.setState({ name: '', email: '', phone: '', loading: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contact">
                <div className="contact-flex">
                    <div className="contact-right">
                        <h1>GET IN TOUCH</h1>
                        <div>
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST">
                                <label htmlFor="name">NAME</label>
                                <br />
                                <input
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    value={this.state.name}
                                    type="text"
                                    id="name"
                                    name="name"
                                    placeholder="Your full name..."
                                    required
                                />
                                <br />

                                <label htmlFor="phone">PHONE</label>
                                <br />
                                <input
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    type="text"
                                    id="phone"
                                    name="phone"
                                    placeholder="Your phone number..."
                                    value={this.state.phone}
                                    required
                                />
                                <br />

                                <label htmlFor="email">EMAIL</label>
                                <br />
                                <input
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    type="email"
                                    id="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    placeholder="Your email address..."
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    required
                                />
                                <br />

                                {!this.state.loading && (
                                    <button className="contact-button" type="submit">
                                        Send
                                    </button>
                                )}

                                {this.state.loading && (
                                    <button className="contact-button" type="submit">
                                        Message Sent
                                    </button>
                                )}
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="copy">
                    <img src={copy} className="copysvg" alt="copy"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Node Backend (Nodemailer):

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const creds = require('./config');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const htmlEmail = `
            Name: ${req.body.name}
            Phone: ${req.body.phone}
            Email: ${req.body.email}
        `;

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
            port: 587,
            auth: {
                user: 'MYEMAILHERE',
                pass: 'MYPASSWORDHERE',
            },
        });

        let mailOptions = {
            from: req.body.name,
            to: 'TOTHISEMAIL',
            subject: 'Potential Client Message From The Workshop',
            html: htmlEmail,
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
            console.log('message sent');
        });
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: you can add async/await to your function ` async handleSubmit(e)`
and before sand you should set `loading` state to `true`
and after `await axios.post('/api/contact'` set `loading` state to `false`

Next you can use `loading` state to display for condition in your jsx code

Comment: also state what you know use to display button, you can rename to something `isDataSent`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will check it later and get back. AFK now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript in the browser is async so when you do post a request, while you getting result this.resetForm function is already called

Make these changes to code:

```
toggleLoading = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        loading: !prevState.loading
    })
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, phone } = this.state;
    this.toggleLoading()
    axios.post('/api/contact', {
        name,
        email,
        phone,
    })
    .then(result => {
        this.resetForm();
        //something
    })
    .catch(err => {
        //something
        this.toggleLoading()
    });
}

resetForm() {
    this.setState({ name: '', email: '', phone: '', loading: false });
}
```

NOTE: in resetForm change loading to false

Suggestion:
you don't need to write to button for saving. just do this

```
<button className="contact-button" type="submit">
    {this.state.loading ? 'Saving...' : 'Send'}
</button>
```

You don't need this

```
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

if you are using the arrow function unless you are using very old react version

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and quick comment. I will check it later and reply. AFK now. :)

Comment: also you need to add new state like sent: true/false, make state true on success and show the message accordingly. There are many way you can do this. just a suggestion